# Force orientation change or allow scroll left/right

Tags: android, layout

I am in the process of updating an app I have, at the moment if the device is not a tablet it will force the orientation to horizontal mode because the information displayed wouldn't fit on phones (something never really sat too well with me).

I did try and come up with a better layout, but it's not my strong point and I couldn't. Below is an example of the data shown in the app.

[image]

UX wise is it better to force orientation change or show all the information on a phone and add a left/right scroll?

Comment: You've already figured out that a new layout is the correct answer. If you are unable to find it yourself you should seek help from a design consultant. Work for what is best for the user.

Answer (score 2):

Why not try **different layout** for portrait and landscape mode.

**In landscape mode**, keep the current layout as shown in your example.

**In portrait mode**, change the layout to some kind of multi-row info card. This makes it easier to scroll and still keep the information overview.

Colors and fonts are just an example.

[image]

Comment: Looking more into the max length of the different fields [this](https://i.imgur.com/OM6dIOO.png) would (currently) be what the most extreme case would look like. I definitely do need to look more into this before deciding anything.

Comment: Just remember to not clutter up things to much. My example was built with the aim to make it easy to find the information I need to know at this moment. (Please mark my answer as the correct one if you were satisfied with my answer).

Answer (score 0):

**Try not to change the orientation as much as possible.** Most users will use their phones in one orientation, one-handed portrait mostly. So, changing orientation is a bad choice.

Anyways, I think these articles sum up of the better practices in detail.

1. https://www.digitalgov.gov/2014/10/28/trends-on-tuesday-8-ways-to-format-tables-for-responsive-web-design/
2. https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-table-roundup/
3. http://exisweb.net/responsive-table-plugins-and-patterns

I prefer the scrollable frame. Put the table in a container that has 100% width, then the table inside with defined width. Then use overflow-x: scroll on the container.